# K8s anti affinity for different clusters

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment file for a k8s cluster in the cloud with an anti affinity rule which prevents multiple pods of same deployment on the same node. This works well but not for my local k8s which uses a single node. I can't seem to find a way to use same deployment file for remote cluster and local cluster.

I have tweaked the affinity and node selector rules to no avail.

Comment: What is the problem on your local cluster -- are the pods failing to deploy, or something else? Can you show us what your deployment looks like?

Comment: Why don't you use something like k3d and run multiple nodes locally?